# php: Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

I am trying to create a MVC framework therefore I have to change the urls and to do this, I have to configure the .htaccess file. Following commands are written in the file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA.L]
```

I am using the wamp server and rewrite_module is checked in apache modules, still getting the Internal server error as:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

What is the solution to the problem?

Comment: The first step to debug problems with apaches rewriting module is ALWAYS to check the servers error log file. The next step is to switch on the additional rewriting log the module offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Notice the `,` not `.`